# Table data not rerendering after state change with useEffect and setState

Tags: reactjs

I have a table with a filter. The filter is triggered by a `select` dropdown. I can see in the console that the list has been updated, however, I don't see the change occurring on screen

```
    // where the rows are rendered
    const renderAdvisors = map((advisor) => (
      <Row advisor={advisor} key={advisor.id} />
    ));
   // HOW I ORIGINALLY GET THE TABLE DATA - IS THE USEMEMO THE PROBLEM?
       const sortedAdvisors = useMemo(
    () => {
      ...
      ...
      
    },
    [arrayOrder, advisors]
  );

   // WHERE I GET MY UPDATED DATA AFTER THE FITLER (I CAN SEE THE NEW LIST IN CONSOLE
  const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState("ALL")
  
  // this useeffect causes a rerender so theoretically the new data would be rendered
  useEffect(() => { 
    filteredAdvisors = sortedAdvisors.filter(obj => obj.location === 
      filtered.toUpperCase());
    console.log('filtered advisors', filteredAdvisors, 'sortedadv', sortedAdvisors)
  },[filtered])
  
  // Below is wht changes the filter with usestate
  const onChangeFilter = (e) => {
    setFiltered(e.value)
  }
   
   return (
   ...
   ...
   // HERES WHERE I SWAP OUT THE LISTS AND AM EXPECTING A RE-RENDER BUT NONE OCCURS
    {advisors.length ?
    renderAdvisors(filteredAdvisors.length ? filteredAdvisors:sortedAdvisors)
    :
    <pw-body size="large" color="grey">Please enter a value</pw-body>
  }
  </tbody>
  ...
  )
```

Comment: You get the new data inside `useEffect` but you don't set it anywhere? is `setFiltered()` in the correct place?

Comment: I think its in the right place. When a user changes the filter, the onChangeFilter updates the filter, and it is used in the filter method to update the filteredAdvisors variable. That variable is a list of the filtered array

Comment: So, `filteredAdvisors` is the state variable for the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make it clear, I created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-dawn-jgjp3?file=/src/App.js). You can start typing "a" or "ab" to see how filter works. The important thing here is to store the variable inside the state, which you already solved.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. thanks to @Sinan Yaman

I was unthinkingly using a regular variable and not a state, so the update wasnt happening.